# access.log customized with php using .htaccess for call file php, is possibile?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Not having access to file access.log of webserver, can i detect all access to website using .htaccess for to call a file .php where with it i work for make something of customized like to access.log?

---

Question is different from other. 
I need to can count all access to a file (audio, music, etc). Solution was access.log but i can't use it. So need solve detecting access and calling a php file for to do from counter.

Comment: No, not really. You can create custom logging though.

Comment: well, how i can detect file using .htaccess and call a php file (where i store it in a database). About php file i know but about htaccess file how i set for call php file all time which there is a request?

Comment: You should route all requests through a single routing script. In there you can log to wherever you want, into a database or a file, as you like.

Comment: You cannot use .htaccess for this.

Comment: ok, for the script but how i can to do it? Mean route all request to php script? My problem is this.